# Why does GCR's container registry ignore the _catalog pagination parameters

Tags: docker, gcloud, docker-registry, google-cloud-console

While trying to query my GCR [container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/) using the [_catalog](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/pagination) API with a pagination parameter I observed that there is no pagination mechanism as descriped in Docker's documentation.

```bash
$ TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
$ curl -v -u _token:${TOKEN} -X GET "https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog?n=1"
```

I see that you get all the repositories at once. I would expect to get a single repository instead. Here is the response's body:

```bash
{"repositories":["image1","image2","image3", ... , "image2016"]}
```

The response's headers has no information regards the way GCR processed the request, namely the following query returns the same result as the above:

```bash
curl -v -u _token:${TOKEN} -X GET "https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog"
```

Google says it supports all the V2 docker registry API.

Comment: Seems google doesn't do pagination at all, I pushed more than 200 images and a single curl brought them all. `curl -v -u _token:${TOKEN} -X GET "https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog"`

Comment: AFAIK google will add the pagination support soon.